# Is the function continuous and differentiable at $x=-2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity

The function $f: (-3, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x^2+5x+7}{x+3} & \mathrm{for} \; -3 < x < -2 \\
1 & \mathrm{for} \; x = -2 \\
-x-e^{-x}+e^2-1 & \mathrm{for} \; x > -2
 \end{cases}$$

1. Is the function continuous at $x=-2$?
2. Is the function differentiable at $x=-2$?

**My attempt:**

**Question 1.** $$\lim_{x \to (-2)^{-}} \frac{x^2+5x+7}{x+3} = \frac{(-2)^2+5(-2)+7}{-2+3} = 1$$

$$\lim_{x \to (-2)^{+}} -x-e^{-x}+e^2-1 = -(-2)-e^{-(-2)}+e^2-1 = 1$$

Therefore the function approaches 1 form both sides, which equals $f(-2)=1$, so it is continuous at $x=-2$.

**Question 2.**

The derivative of $f_1(x)= \frac{x^2+5x+7}{x+3}$ is  $$f'_1(x)= \frac{(x+3)(2x+5)-(x^2+5x+7)}{(x+3)^2}$$

We have $f_1'(-2)=0$.

The derivative of $f_2(x)= -x-e^{-x}+e^2-1$ is  $$f'_2(x)=-1+e^{-x}$$

We have $f_2'(-2)=-1+e^{-2}$.

Because $f_1'(-2) \neq f_2'(-2)$, the function is not differentiable.

---

Is this correct? Any suggestions for writing it down better?

Comment: The main idea is correct. I did not check every step.

Comment: @Peter Okay, thank you. That is the most important of course.

Comment: Technically it's not correct, but the idea behind it is correct. The derivatives that you calculated weren't defined at 2, and so you can't evaluate them at 2. To be formal, you would calculate the right and left limit of the difference quotient for those functions.

Comment: The first part(question) is flawless,For the second part,you have to use the definition of the derivative-both limits at $2$.

Comment: @JDrinas Can you explain why I can't just use the quotient rule?

Comment: You can't because,as Bob rightly argues,the function-in the form of the quotient-is not defined in $2$.It is a constant in $2$ equal to $1$.What you  are interested in calculating a derivative are the right and left limits.Exactly as you do with the limit above-a derivative is nothing more than a limit of a function(a particular expression of a given function to be precise-the one given by the definition of the derivative.).

Comment: In a more formal language: A function $f:I⊆ℝ$ is said to be differentiable in an internal point $a$ of $I$ iff there exists the two side limits in $a$: $f_+'(a)$ and $f_-'(a)$ and they are equal. So you have to verify that these two limits exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a change of variable $x = -2 + h.$  now look at $$\frac{x^2 + 5x + 7}{x+3} = \frac{4 -4h - 10+10h + 7 + 4h^2}{1+h} = (1+6h+\cdots)(1 - h + \cdots) = 1+5h+\cdots\\
-x-e^{-x}+e^2 - 1=2-h-e^2(1-h+\cdots)+e^2 - 1=1+(e^2 - 1)h+\cdots$$

you can see that the graph of $y=(x)f$ at $(-2, 1)$ have slopes $5$ on the left and $e^2 - 1$ on the right of $x = -2.$  therefore it is not differentiable at $x = -2.$

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @wythagoras, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It **is** true that, while the derivative is not necessarily continuous, it **does** satisfy the "intermediate value property" so that, if you have that theorem, it is sufficient to show that the limits from the two directions are equal.