# Find all asymptotes of the function

Tags: calculus

Follow-up on [Is the function continuous and differentiable at $x=-2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296564/is-the-function-continuous-and-differentiable-at-x-2)

The function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is given by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{x^2+5x+7}{x+3} & \mathrm{for} \; x < -3 \\
0 & \mathrm{for} \; x = -3 \\
\frac{x^2+5x+7}{x+3} & \mathrm{for} \; -3 < x < -2 \\
1 & \mathrm{for} \; x = -2 \\
-x-e^{-x}+e^2-1 & \mathrm{for} \; x > -2
 \end{cases}$$

Find all asymptotes of the function.

---

**My attempt:**

$$\frac{x^2+5x+7}{x+3}=x+\frac{2x+7}{x+3}=x+2+\frac{1}{x+3}$$

So the first part of the function has the oblique asymptote $y=x+2$.

Then we have the vertical asymptote $x=-3$.

Then the last part, $-e^{-x}$ goes to zero as $x \to \infty$, so we have the oblique asymptote $y=-x+e^2-1$ here.

---

Is this correct? I think I am missing something here.

Isn't it necessary to proof that this are the only asymptotes? If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That all looks good to me.

I wouldn't expect you to need to prove that no others exist, but the basic idea behind it would be that non-vertical asymptotes only occur due to end behavior ($x \to \pm \infty$), and you've taken care of those two oblique asymptotes. Vertical asymptotes only occur with division by zero, and you've taken care of that as well, when $x \to -3$.